# convert numeric value to English words

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I convert a Numeric value `3600` to `three thousand and sixty`? Is this possible in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ToWords()` and `ProperCase()` functions.

```
//{@ConvertCurrency}
// returns Five Thousand
ProperCase( ToWords(5000, 0) )
```

Comment: Excellent answer. It looks like @Ganeshgm7 wants them in lowercase, though. So I'd recommend replacing `ProperCase()` with `lcase()`